# Unable to insert data in MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbee in web developing. I was checking how to update data from a form to a database in server with php. I seem to be able to connect to the database, but not able to update data.

the html for the form:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Experiment with php and db</title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="formact.php">
     <p><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="first name"/></p>
     <p><input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="last name"/></p>
     <p><textarea name="words" placeholder="Enter what you think"></textarea></p>
     <p><button type="submit"></button></p>
   </form>
 </body>
```

And here is the formact.php

```
<?php
 $name=$_POST['fname']." ".$_POST['lname'];
 $ta=$_POST['words'];
 $con = mysql_connect();
 $msg="status 0";
 if (!$con)
   {
          $msg="db connect failed";
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   if ($con)
   $msg="db connected";
 mysql_select_db("php_test",$con);
 $success=mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (title, blog_entry) VALUES ('$name','$ta')");
 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Form with php</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 echo $name."<br/>";
 echo $ta."<br/>";
 echo $msg."<br/>";
 if(!$success)
 echo "DB update failed..";
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am getting the `$msg=="db connected"` and `!success==true` in the echo.
Can you please point me out where am I doing wrong?

Comment: some DB users are restricted in altering the contents. So first check is to see if your user has write permissions.

Comment: You should really be using `mysqli_*` as a minimum. If you're trying to learn PHP, avoid outdated APIs such as `mysql_*`

Comment: Change if(!$success) echo "DB update failed.."; to if (!$success) echo 'Error: '.mysql_error(); and rerun so we can see what the error is.

Comment: Also, are you really wanting to **update** the data, or **insert** the data?

Comment: @BenM: `mysqli_*` is deprecated too, as far as I know. PDO is the current standard (and works great, too).

Comment: @BenM I want to insert a new row in news table in the database.

Comment: Say hello to my friend [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Bobby — `mysqli_*` is not deprecated.

Comment: I was learning from w3schools.com (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) and they are suggesting to use mysql_connect

Comment: @VictorMukherjee — W3Schools are awful. Their PHP/MySQL tutorials were dangerous when they were written and are now out of date *and* dangerous. Try http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: For the sanity of everyone here, please don't use W3Schools. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @Matt Humphrey: I tried what you suggested, but the mysql_error() seems to be returning an empty string. I only get 'Error'.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee, please don't use w3schools, see [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: @Bobby - where on earth do you have that from? `mysqli_*` certainly isn't deprecated!

Comment: @BenM: Yeah, I just checked again and I could swear that I read somewhere that mysqli should be/is deprecated in favor of PDO. :/ Odd...I wonder where I got that idea...

Comment: Try changing this line: `$success=mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (title, blog_entry) VALUES ('$name','$ta')"); ` to this: `$success=mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (title, blog_entry) VALUES ('$name','$ta')") or  die(mysql_error());  `. This will show an error message that might help you identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've last touched php so this might not help at all but you could try these 2 things I'm going to propose:

1) I'm not sure but I believe that if you want to use `$success` you need to close the `mysql_close($con);` after using it.

2) Are you sure `!$success` is valid?? I mean `!` is usually a not but what does !success mean? empty?

Like I said I might be totally wrong,just trying to help...

Answer (score 1):

first of all just echo the whole query with attaching "mysql_query" to it, 
then run that query on phpmyadmin there you can easily point out your error and just correct it.
and by doing echo you can also see whether values are coming from the post or not...

Answer (score 0):

First of all mysql_* is deprecated You should use mysqli_* or PDO

Second connect to database accordingly as

```
<pre>   
    <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password'); //By default mysql_user=>root and mysql_password='' mean empty
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysqli_select_db("php_test", $con);

    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO news (title, blog_entry)
    VALUES ('$name','$ta')");
    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```